# top left and top right button

Tags: element

I want to know How to create top left button and top right button element on a single row using css or jquery.

Please kindly provide details step by step.

Thanks
MHB

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you link to an example, or add a picture?

Comment: See the below link
http://www.linkedin.com/ 

Answers: Information Security                            edit| X

Answer (score 2):

[Floatutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/tutorial0513.htm)

1st result for Google: `css top left right button`.

Comment: +1 No idea if that's what he's looking for, but glad to have the link!

Comment: Dear Sir
  I tried it but not found any resource which helpful for me. 
  Sir if you know, Please help me.

Thanks
MHB